# Unity .desktop file not doing anything

Tags: .desktop

I am new to Linux, and I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I am trying to create a `.desktop` file for the simplest code ever. However, I can't figure out why, but when I double-click it, nothing happens besides the fact that the icon shows up in the Launcher for a few seconds.

Here's my .desktop file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Shortcut-Test
Comment=No comment for now
Exec=/home/julien/Desktop/Test.sh
Icon=/home/julien/Desktop/Pic.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Here's the Test.sh file it runs :

```
#!/bin/bash
python Test.py
```

Here's the target Test.py file :

```
f = open("Test.txt", "w") 
f.write("Test successful!")
f.close()
```

The .desktop, .sh and .py files are all in `/home/julien/Desktop` and have permissions `chmod +x`. When I run Test.sh from the terminal, everything works fine and the Test.txt file is created. However, when I double-click on my Shortcut-Test icon, nothing seems to happen.

**Does anyone manage to make this simple example work?
Any help is welcome!**

Comment: If this was working from a terminal then you must have been at the Desktop prompt. To use via the .desktop launcher then  Test.sh must use full path to Test.py, i.e. `python  /home/julien/Desktop/Test.py`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run the python script you have to put the full path or ./Desktop/Test.py in the sh file because when you run the Test.sh file the path where the script will run in /home/julien, so it is just a problem of bad files locations of the files or misleadings paths. It helps to "debug" to set the Terminal=true and adding some waiting time to the Test.sh file (e.g. sleep 20 in the end of the file) to see the output of the script

Comment: Thanks for bot the help and the debugging tip.. works fine now!